# loop over list of selected object properties in python to create a tree view

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, pyqt

I have an object `Restaurant`

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, name, location, phone, parent = None):
        self.staff = []
        self.tables = []
        self.menu = []
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.phone = phone

        self.dict = {"Staff": self.staff, "Tables": self.tables, "Menu": self.menu}

    def addStaff(self, staff_object):
        self.staff.append(staff_object)
```

Then I add new staff object (with some properties) to the list `self.staff` with class method `addStaff`.

After the object(s) are added I print the `self.dict` and it is still empty. What is the right way to "update" the values in `self.dict` to get the right values and eventually display them in tree view like:

-staff
---staff_1
---staff_2
--...
-tables
---table_1
---table_2
--...
-menus
---menu_1
---menu_2
---menu_3

Comment: how are you instantiating your class and adding the items? Where are the staff objects coming from?

Comment: It's a part of GUI (under construction) and I initialize it in:

    class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
            restaurant = Restaurant(Name, London, 000)

Each staff object is created with properties from file staff_prop.txt in folder staff

Comment: so you instantiate a staff object and append it to the staff list?

Comment: Yes (at the moment). But the plan is to create (and assign object properties) within GUI (input window). As I understand the objects should then be appended to the list?

Comment: I added an answer which adds items using methods and accessing the attributed directly. The items are in the dict when it is printed so if that does not work for you, I think you need to add more of your code.

Comment: I don't see the bug in the provided code. Does anything else modify `self.staff` or `self.dict`? Can you provide a [stripped-down, runnable test case that demonstrates the bug](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I could try, but it will take some time as it is part of GUI (under construction). As said if I only print `self.staff` it returns list of objects, but if I print `self.rest_dict` in next line it returns empty list.

Comment: @user2357112
if you could maybe look at the actual code, it's on:
[link](https://github.com/avstenit/DyS/tree/master/DyS_V37)
the problem I have with file `MBD_system.py` class `MBDsystem` line 63 and 113 return empy dictionary `self.model_view_dictionary` but between these lines objects are appended to list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of how to add to instantiate  your class and add items.

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, name, location, phone, parent = None):
        self.staff = []
        self.tables = []
        self.menu = []
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.phone = phone

        self.rest_dict = {"Staff": self.staff, "Tables": self.tables, "Menu": self.menu}

    def addStaff(self, staff_object):
        self.staff.append(staff_object)

    def addTables(self, table_object):
        self.tables.append(table_object)

    def addMenu(self, menu_object):
        self.menu.append(menu_object)
r = Restaurant("foo","bar",911) # instantiate 
r.addStaff("Foo")
r.addStaff("Bar") # append using method
r.staff.append("Foo1") # you can also  access attributes directly
r.addMenu("Lunch")
r.addMenu("Dinner")
r.menu.append("Lunch")
r.addTables(1)
r.addTables(2)
r.tables.append(3)
print r.rest_dict

{'Menu': ['Lunch', 'Dinner', 'Lunch'], 'Tables': [1, 2, 3], 'Staff': ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Foo1']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice example - it is working just the way I want. Unfortunately I have quite similar code, but it returns me empty list after it should be filled as I print only self.staff and it returns list of objects. I think I will have to look in the code a little more :) Or could you maybe look at the code?

Comment: You're welcome, if you want to post a link to your code in pastebin I will have a look

Comment: Here's the situation. If I run only the file where the class `Restaurant` is it is working. But if I run the class `Restaurant` within file `main.py` it is not working - somewhere here should be the problem...
I think pasting it to pasting wouldn't be very practical (multiple files, packages), but I will keep it in mind as a last resort. Thanks once again for the help.

Comment: No worries you're welcome. so you import Restaurant in main.py and instantiate and add items there but nothing shows when you print `instance.rest_dict`?

Comment: Restaurant is imported in main.py yes. But items are added in Restaurant method `__init__` if the folder is specified. I also work directly with `self.staff` (and other properties) through the code and the data is read/used correctly. I only have problems with this newly implemented dictionary. If I print only `self.staff` the data is there, but if I print dictionary it is empty as when it is created.

Comment: I will try replicating your code and see what I can come up with

Comment: just post your main.py in pastebin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56495/discussion-between-avstenit-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: I suggested to continue the dialogue in discussion. As I still have problems I would kindly ask you for your advice.

Comment: @avstenit i will have a look at your code in github and be online in two hours to chat

Answer (score 2):

Your real code contains lines like

```
self.joints = ...
```

instead of appending to the lists like the code you posted. That doesn't modify the existing list; that points the `self.joints` attribute to a new list, while everything that had a reference to the old list is unaffected. From then on, anything that accesses `self.joints` uses the new list, while anything that uses, say, `self.model_view[2]`, uses the old list.

Don't do that. If you want to set the contents of an existing list, slice-assign the contents in:

```
self.joints[:] = ...
```

In general, never assign directly to a variable if what you really want to modify is the object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment  I was thinking in this direction. Based on your comment I think that `self.bodies` is done the right way each body object is appended to list `self.bodies` which is also inside dictionary - this should get updated or not? As I see it is equal to the example posted here.

What I would like to get is that I can manipulate some lists in a for loop so I planned to use dictionary. And if I modify any of the list in dictionary (append/remove object) and after I access the list from dictionary the updated list will be displayed.

Comment: @avstenit: As long as nothing assigns directly to `self.bodies` after its creation, it should be fine.

Comment: @avstenit: I checked, and you have at least one direct assignment to `self.bodies` after initial creation: https://github.com/avstenit/DyS/blob/master/DyS_V37/MBD_system/MBD_system.py#L139

Comment: Using `append()` is direct assignment and is not ok? How should non-direct assignment of object element to list look like?

Comment: @avstenit: What? No! `append` is fine. I linked to a line that says `self.bodies = []`.

Comment: Ok. I would like just to clarify some things so I will add some line number to make things clear :)
What the code does (regarding `self.bodies` and `self.model_view_dictionary`:
1. line 56-the `self.bodies` is initialized in method `__init()__`   
2. line 63-the (empty list) `self.bodies` is added to dictionary `self.model_view_dictionary` with key `Bodies`   
3. line 179-body objects are appended to list `self.bodies` in method `create_bodies`  
4. line 97-if you print `self.model_view_dictionary` one line before and line after you'll get same (empty list) result - empty list for key `Bodies`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56556/discussion-between-avstenit-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem it was in line 84. I changed it from:

```
if not self.MBD_system_constructed
```

to:

```
if self.MBD_system_constructed
```